# htaccessのリダイレクトループに関して

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccessについての質問です

あるblogディレクトリに次のように記されたhtaccessファイルがあります

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/blog/view/([0-9]+)/?$   /php/article$1 [L]
```

しかし何かのきっかけで、検索エンジンは前者のアドレスだけでなく、
後者のアドレスを不本意にもインデックスしてしまいしました。
このphpディレクトリを含む後者のアドレスのインデックスを検索エンジンから正式に取り除くには、
phpディリクトリにhtaccessファイルを置き、
そこに前者のアドレスへのリダイレクトを記さないといけませんが、
この場合必ずループに陥ります。どうすればよいでしょうか。

phpディレクトリを含むアドレスをインデックスさせないように
ルートにrobots.txtファイルを設置することで対策は十分でしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

httpd-2.4 以降であれば、`[END]` フラグが利用できます。

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/view/([0-9]+)/?$   /php/article$1 [END]
RewriteRule ^php/article([0-9]+)$    /blog/view/$1 [R,END]
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。残念ながら使用しているサーバのapacheのバージョンは2.2でした。ホームディレクトリ直下のhtaccessファイルにまとめて指示を書けることは勉強になりました。